# Dynamical Matrix for the Thermal Transmission Coefficient Calculation

Tags: density-functional-theory, phonopy, phonon-dispersion, lattice-thermal-conductivity, phono3py

The dynamical matrix for the thermal transmission coefficient calculation is written as follows:
$$D_{I\alpha,J\beta}(\overrightarrow{q})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{M_{I}M_{J}}}\sum_{b}K_{I\alpha,J\beta}(a,b)e^{i\cdot\overrightarrow{q}(\vec{R}_{b}-\vec{R}_{a})}\tag{1}$$
,where $M_{I}$ and $M_{J}$ are atomic weight; $\vec{R}_{a}$ and $\vec{R}_{b}$ are the original lattice constant.

$K_{I\alpha,J\beta}$ is the force constant matrix and it is given as follows:
$$K_{I\alpha,J\beta}(R-R^{'})=\frac{\partial^{2}E_{tot}}{\partial{\mu_{I\alpha}}(R)\partial{\mu_{J\beta}(R^{'})}}=-\frac{\partial{F_{I\alpha}}}{\partial{\mu_{J\beta}(R^{'})}}\tag{2}$$

1. Compute the force constant matrix for the unit cell and this force constant matrix is $3n\times3n$ matrix; for example, if there are three atoms in the unit cell; then, this force constant matrix is a $9\times9$ matrix.
2. Compute the dynamical matrix through summing all the neighbour cell of the central unit cell
3. Symmterize the dynamical matrix and make sure the upper and lower triangle blocks in this dynamical matrix are hermitian conjugate to each other.

Is my understanding correct or not?

Comment: +1 but please see [this](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/421/5) if you're wondering why your post was edited.